# Ng-repeat in Sightly

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, aem, sightly

I am trying to populate drop-down values using ng-repeat in Sightly. The AEM node saves my data as String array and I am able to fetch it properly, but not able to populate them as it throws "`? undefined:undefined ?`" error.

My code:

```
<select name="${validation.elementName}" id="${validation.elementName}" ng-model="${validation.elementName}" ng-change="${properties.clickfunction}">
        <option ng-repeat="opt in ${properties.options}" value={{opt}}>opt</option>                 
        </select>
```

And the output:

[image: output]:

Is there anything I am missing? As Sightly is totally new to me. I will be very grateful for any help to improve this code or pointing my mistake.

Comment: Is there a particular reason not to use `ng-options`?

Comment: As my project is having different team for HTML, Development and Application, I am in a position to construct components based on the comps provided by html team :( You can say it's a sad architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to wrap the data you pass to `value` in quotes, so it should be like this:

```
value="{{opt}}"
```

Second, it looks like you are passing the values without single quotes and they are not being recognized as strings. Take a look at this plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/A2gZJbvVV9ozHloLkF4B?p=preview

You can see that the first `ng-repeat` works as expected, but the second throws an error in the console and doesn't display anything. Basically, you just need to put quotes around each string in your array.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Victor for your reply.

Please find my below findings.

1. value="{{opt}}" was my mistake while pasting the code to stackoverflow.
2. ${properties.options} returns string array.
3. ng-repeat seems to parse correctly as per this output.[image: this]

Comment: It looks like you are passing the values without single quotes and they are not being recognized as strings. Take a look at this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/A2gZJbvVV9ozHloLkF4B?p=preview You can see that the first `ng-repeat` works as expected, but the second throws an error in the console and doesn't display anything. Basically, you just need to put quotes around each string in your array

Comment: Thanks @Victor. The above one worked perfectly. Can you edit your first answer or post the above as answer so that I can mark as correct.